# Critical Section - Only Single thread "sleeps" on lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, critical-section

I have a critical section (using `lock`ed scope).

I'd like that only the latest incoming thread "sleeps" on it. Hence - once the critical section is locked, every incoming thread "terminates" all previous sleeping ones.

Is there a way to achieve this using C#?

Thank you

Comment: `lock` uses `Monitor` class under the hood, you can try to get the desired behavior using `Monitor` or `Semaphore`

Comment: Can you define what is supposed to happen to the other threads?

Comment: @MoB. other threads are terminated and collected by GC

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism that seemed most effective for accomplishing this was to use Tasks, so the solution below is actually asynchronous, rather than synchronous, as the code came out much simpler that way.  If you need it to be synchronous, you can just synchronously wait on the Tasks.

```
public class SingleWaiterLock
{
    private bool realLockTaken = false;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> waiterTCS = null;
    private object lockObject = new object();

    public Task<bool> WaitAsync()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (!realLockTaken)
            {
                realLockTaken = true;
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            if (waiterTCS == null)
            {
                waiterTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                return waiterTCS.Task;
            }
            else
            {
                waiterTCS.SetResult(false);
                waiterTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                return waiterTCS.Task;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (waiterTCS != null)
            {
                waiterTCS.SetResult(true);
                waiterTCS = null;
            }
            else
            {
                realLockTaken = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The boolean returned from the wait method indicates whether you actually acquired the lock (if it returns true) or were booted by someone coming later (returning false).  The lock should only be released (but must always be released) when wait returns true.